# How do I format EVO 256GB and 512 GB using the SoundTrap ST600 software?

Tags: soundtrap, hydrophone, acoustic-monitoring, sdcard

When I put a new SD card in the soundtrap, the software gives me IO error i have try to format it according to the user's manual but when I insert this new card, the software doesn't react. This doesn't happen when I use the EVO SD card that comes with the soundtrap.

Hope anyone can Help me!
Mario

Here is a picture of the SD card I´m trying to use
[image]

Comment: Does [this question](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/1439/how-do-i-format-the-evo-256gb-sd-cards-using-the-soundtrap-st600-software-versi) help at all?

Comment: Also, is your new SD card a different brand than EVO? Could you add that info to your question. I know SoundTrap recommends a very specific brand/type of SD card.

Comment: Also the size and class may matter. (maybe show a picture?)

Comment: Hi, thanx for your answers, I just added a picture of the SD card I´m trying to use. Hope this helps

Comment: According to the SoundTrap manual that one (any Samsung EVO microSD) should be fine. Is your computer able to see the card, even though the SoundTrap software does not?

Comment: As @selene suggested, did you try it on computer and did it work there as expected?

Comment: thnx, yes. I have used this SD card before with other hydrophones and with my computer and it didn't gave me any problems. I Format it but it didnt work.